# Equation for spacing of elements on the edge of a circle

Tags: circles, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to come up with an equation which, given an index within an arbitary number of elements (the most natural example would be 12, as in 12 numbers on a clock), along with an arbitrary radius, provides the point at which that element should be placed.

For example, if we are to use the example of a clock, and consider the center of the circle as the point `[0, 0]`, and using a radius of, say, `100`, then the '12' would be located at `[0, -100]`, the '3' located at `[100, 0]`, the '6' at `[0, -100]`, and so on.

Does anyone know of an equation I could use to find the point for an arbitrary index using an arbitrary number of elements?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know trigonometry? Sine and cosine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and welcome to the site.

Suppose you have $n$ elements, and you want to look at the co-ordinates of the $i$th element, and you have a radius of $r$.  Then the co-ordinates are simply:

$(r\cdot\cos(2\pi\cdot\frac{i}{n}),r\cdot\sin(2\pi\cdot\frac{i}{n}))$

Or if you're more used to using degrees than radians:

$(r\cdot\cos(360^\circ\cdot\frac{i}{n}),r\cdot\sin(360^\circ\cdot\frac{i}{n}))$

This assumes that your circle is centered at $(0,0)$.  If your circle is centered instead at $(a,b)$, then you simply add $a$ and $b$ to your co-ordinates:

$(a + r\cdot\cos(2\pi\cdot\frac{i}{n}),b + r\cdot\sin(2\pi\cdot\frac{i}{n}))$

In these cases, per common mathematical convention, the numbering starts along the $x$-axis with $i=1$, and goes around evenly until $i=n-1$.  If $i=n$ it simply starts again.  If you need to change the direction or starting point, that is also possible.

For example, if you wanted to start at $90^\circ$, simply add $90^\circ$ inside the trig function (or $\pi/2$ if you're working with radians):

$(a+r\cdot\cos(360^\circ\cdot\frac{i}{n}+90^\circ),r\cdot\sin(360^\circ\cdot\frac{i}{n}+90^\circ))$

Comment: Do you have a strong preference for $r.\cos\theta$ instead of $r\cdot\cos\theta$ and $360^o$ instead of $360^\circ$?  I changed $r.\cos$ to $r\cos$ and you changed it back to $r,\cos$, then I changed it to $r\cdot\cos$ and you changed it back to $r.\cos$.  I also changed $360^o$ to $360^\circ$, which is standard usage, and you changed it back to $306^o$.

Comment: Apologies.  I didn't actually change it back.  I was editing the original, and saw that someone else had made an edit, but couldn't see what it was.  I have a strong preference for your version!

Comment: I'll edit it, if you tell me how you did the degree sign?  I tried a couple of things that I remembered.  The other is, I assume \cdot.

Comment: If you right-click on $360^\circ$, you see how it's coded.  It's 360^\circ. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: That's even more helpful!  Teach a man to fish, and all that!  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the help! This is working very well. You mentioned that if I needed to change the starting point I could do so - how would one do that? I need it to start at 90, rather than 0.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an example.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for all the help! This is working excellent. By the way, it seems your formatting is a bit off in your edit (specifically the `$\pi/2`).